# CardView aligning inside RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm using `RecyclerView` with `LinearLayoutManager`, items are `CardViews`. All cards have fixed (in pixels) width. RecyclerView is placed inside `SwipeRefreshLayout`, if that matters.

How to horizontally align each `RecyclerView` item using only xml? Applying `android:layout_gravity="center"` to cards have no effect.

Part with the RecyclerView:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/news_recycler_view"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Card layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/CardStyle">

    ...
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Style:

```
<style name="CardStyle" parent="CardView.Light">
     ...
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">8dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">@dimen/cardview_width</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try wrapping a CardView inside a LinearLayout with gravity="center"

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">                

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
           android:id="@+id/news_recycler_view"
           android:paddingTop="16dp"
           android:paddingBottom="16dp"
           android:clipToPadding="false"
           android:layout_width="200dp"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

**EDIT**:

We could try to wrap a childView of RecyclerView inside a linearlayout to accomplish this effect.

I use this trick for my own ViewHolders inside my RecyclerView Adapter as well (lil snippet):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
        card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="20dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/cardview_header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/question_holder"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I've fixed a typo in my question; RecyclerView has `android:layout_width="match_parent"`, so wrapping RecyclerView into LinearLayout have no effect.

Comment: Hmm, I see, I see, my bad, your card views, do they have `layout_width="match_parent"` aswell?

Comment: No, cards have fixed width (like, layout_width=200dp)

Comment: Alright, yes, that works, thanks! I've upvoted you answer and will accept it in a while if nobody suggests a solution without additional layouts (but it feels like there is no such way).